# NServiceBus without spamming my solution with IMessage/NServiceBus references

Tags: nservicebus

Has anyone found a smart way to use NServiceBus, without having to implements that useless IMessage marker interface for all messages?

Especially, when using DomainEvents, I would absolutely hate to couple my domains to a specific servce bus implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IMessage interface is needed so that NServiceBus can automatically register those types in the serializer. When using domain events, it isn't recommended to publish them directly on the bus - instead, a domain event handler would translate them to service-level events (which inherit IMessage).

Comment: Hey Udi, thanks for the quick reply!

Of course it is a marker interface - but having to repeat domain messages to service messages adds quite a bit of cruft - 95% of the time they would be 1:1. I would definitely want to to avoid that, typing isn't my best skill.

It would be great if there was some kind of pluggable convention module that would tell the bus how to recognize a valid message (MEF, name space, class suffix, my own interface...).

I am thinking of using some of those weavers like PostSharp, but I would hate it to add just another level of complexity to this solution.

Comment: You could use something like AutoMapper.

Comment: I would prefer NServiceBus to be more configurable in this regard. I have a project which already uses a marker interface for a message. I don't mind the marker interface being used to business domain code because it describes something specific to the domain. However, now to use NServiceBus I have to reference it in the domain, or create an additional project with translations, which adds another layer of complexity. Moreover, that layer will have to be bound to NServiceBus. While the layer may become necessary, it would be nice to have more options for transitioning into NServiceBus.

Answer (score 5):

I just noticed that Udi is adding an [Unobtrusive Mode](http://support.nservicebus.com/customer/portal/articles/856287--unobtrusive-mode-messages) to NServiceBus 3.0.  It appears
that will address the issue.  There's even a [sample writeup](http://support.nservicebus.com/customer/portal/articles/856287--unobtrusive-mode-messages), but you would have to pull the latest off [github](https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus) at this point (Feb 2012).  If you're willing to put up with some potential instability to get pure POCO messages, you might give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to create your own interfaces implementing the NSB marker interface and then ILMerge the NSB dependencies into your own DLL. This should allow you to only require references to your own Dll and no external references to NSB.

Its what NSB does for its own dependencies so you should be able to extend the idea, be sure to check out the pitfalls of this approach though - Udi blogged about it recently

http://www.udidahan.com/2010/08/01/cautiously-merging-il/

Answer (score 0):

Six months later, still nothing about this issue (fix/improve) ??

Summary of possible solutions: 
   1) ILMerge or..
   2) Custom Dispatcher for custom wrapped messages.

All this because of the IMessage marker interface.